# Codeigniter: Interdependent dropdown lists. Completed code

Tags: codeigniter

I have a series of interdependent select lists which work correctly outside CI. When I tried to implement it in Codeigniter, I am not coming on as the first selectlist is not populated, either the echoing is not properly code or I dont know what. This question here will refer to just the first select list, that is, you will not see any jquery, because the first gets populated directly from the database without any "function change".

so here are the modules:

VIEW

```
<?php echo form_open('control_form/add_all'); ?>
       <label for="f_state">State<span class="red">*</span></label>
        <select id="f_state" name="f_state">
            <option value=""></option>
            <?php

                foreach($result as $row)
                {
                echo '<option value="' . $row->pais_id . '">' . $row->pais_name . '</option>';
                }

            ?>
        </select>

        <label for="f_city">City<span class="red">*</span></label>
        <!--this will be filled based on the tree selection above-->
        <select id="f_city" name="f_city" id="f_city_label"> 
            <option value=""></option>
        </select>

        <label for="f_membername">Member Name<span class="red">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" name="f_membername"/>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

CONTROL

```
public function add_all()
    {

        #Validate entry form information
        $this->load->model('model_form','', TRUE);        
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('f_state', 'State', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('f_city', 'City', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('f_membername', 'Member Name', 'required');

        $data['city'] = $this->model_form->get_state(); //gets the available groups for the dropdown


        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
              $this->load->view('view_form_all', $data); # parece ser que vuelve a meter los mismos datos que tenia la Form
        }
        else
        {
            #Add Member to Database
            $this->model_form->add_all();
            $this->load->view('view_form_success');
        }


    }
```

MODEL

```
<?php
class Model_form extends CI_Model
{
      function __construct()
    {
            // Call the Model constructor
            parent::__construct();
    }

    function get_state()
    {
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT pais_id, pais_name FROM pais');
        return $query->result();
    }


    function add_all()
    {
        $v_state = $this->input->post('f_state');
        $v_membername = $this->input->post('f_membername');

        $data = array(
                'pais_id' => NULL,
                'pais_name' => $v_state

        );

        $this->db->insert('members', $data);
    }



}
```

Comment: Where do you send `$result` to the view?

Comment: hmm I believe here:  $this->load->view('view_form_all', $data);  that, is, $data is the array that came from the Model query to the database. If the select lists have not been touched, then it should load up the view together with the data

Comment: Notice you are sending `$city` and not `$result`. There is no `$result ` variable.

Comment: thank you, yes, you also deserve the right answer. Stackoverflow does not let us to grant correct answers to several people. Since yours was written in a comment and not as an answer, I could not click you right too, but I heartedly thank you.

Comment: Glad it helped. A thank you is more than enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not sending `$result` to the view, you need something like:

```
$data['result'] = ...//get some data
$this->load->view('view_form_all',$data);
```

If the list you want to display is the cities list, then you need to change in your view:

```
foreach($city as $row)
{
      echo '<option value="' . $row->pais_id . '">' . $row->pais_name . '</option>';
}
```

since in your controller you are doing:

```
$data['city'] = $this->model_form->get_state();
```

Comment: but, isn't this  $data['city'] = $this->model_form->get_state(); actually ? :(  is not the same as i have?  $this->load->view('view_form_all', $data);

Comment: yes, but in your view you are calling the wrong parameter, you have `$data['city']`, so in the view, the variable name would be `$city` not `$result`

Comment: Correct! In 3 minutes I can click you answer correct, thank you!